# Parse a csv file in javascript and pull out a dictionary based on two particular rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have some csv files that I need to parse in JS. The file consists of a bunch of rows, which I need to pull out two. One has the headers for this card, the next row is the data.

I am trying to use csv-parse and have managed to unpack the data into json objects, but can't for the life of me work out how to make this work.

I tried regex but of course csv-parse returns objects, not rows as strings.

The files in question have lots of stuff in them. The rows I'm interested in have rows like

```
H,TYPE1,TYPE2,field,field,field.....
followed by
D,TYPE1,TYPE2,value,value,value....
```

The result I'm looking for is a json object with field1:value1, field2:value2 etc.

Whats the best way to do this?

I thought about an arrayAll function to pull out the array with the right fields, but csv-parse returns objects not arrays.. sigh.

I'm sure I'm making this harder than it need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply pre-process the file to extract the relevant content (e.g. the two lines you're interested, then pass this to csv-parse),

For example:

```
const parse = require("csv-parse");
const fs = require("fs");

const filePath = "inline-headers.csv";
const csvContent = getRequiredCsvContent(filePath);

function getRequiredCsvContent(filePath) {
    // Replace with your actual regex pattern...
    let lineMatcher = /header/i;
    let fileLines = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8").split("\n");
    let requiredLines = fileLines.reduce((contentArray, line, index) => { 
        if (lineMatcher.test(line) || (contentArray.length === 1)) {
            contentArray.push(line);
        }
        return contentArray;
    }, []);
    return requiredLines.join("\n");
}

console.log("Extracted csv content:\n", csvContent);
parse(csvContent, {
    delimiter: ",",
    columns: true
}, (err, records) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", err);
    } else { 
        console.log("Records:", records);
    }
});
```

I'm using a test file like so:

**inline-headers.csv**

```
someline01,someline02,someline03
someline11,someline12,someline13
header1,header2,header3
field1,field2,field3
```

I'm including a more specific answer here that's more tailored to your actual problem:

```
const parse = require("csv-parse");
const fs = require("fs");
const filePath = "inline-headers.csv";
const csvContent = getRequiredCsvContent(filePath);

function getRequiredCsvContent(filePath) {
    const lineMatcher = /^(I|D),DISPATCH,UNIT_SOLUTION/;
    let fileLines = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8").split("\n");
    let requiredLines = fileLines.reduce((contentArray, line) => {
        if (lineMatcher.test(line) || (contentArray.length === 1)) {
            contentArray.push(line);
        }
        return contentArray;
    }, []);
    return requiredLines.join("\n")
}

console.log("Extracted csv content:\n", csvContent);
parse(csvContent, {
    delimiter: ",",
    columns: true,
    relax_column_count: true
}, (err, records) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error:", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Records:", records);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm close.

I have the correct two lines in csvContent but the parse command (I had to use parse = require("csv-parse") rather than "csv-parse/lib/sync" if that matters.

Unfortunately rather than unpacking the full words for the header columns, it unpacked each character into its own if that makes sense.

Comment: I'll see if I can replicate that behaviour, then I might be able to find a workaround / fix!

Comment: Thanks Terry, I can send you the file I'm testing against with the code I've come up with if that helps.. not sure if you can pm on here though.

Comment: I've updated with a more specific answer that should address your actual issue!

Comment: That is fantastic Terry, thank you. The only thing I can see is a /r on the last entry in the second set of records.. Now I just need to work out how it actually works.

Comment: Ah yes, we can just do a trim on the fields and we should be ok. Reduce a very useful function, you can do an awful lot with it!

Comment: Yep.. that did it :)